# Creating an array object from a constructor in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, constructor

Is this correct? I am speaking about the this.rates part, and the return.rates part. Trying to construct and array object from a constructor, and return number of array objects in a collection. I am still learning, so forgive me if my terminology is a bit off.

```
public class ArrayFun
{
    // instance variables
    private ArrayList<ArrayRates> rates;


    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class ArrayFun.
     */
    public ArrayFun()
    {
        this.rates = new ArrayList<ArrayRates>();

    }

    /**
     * Return the number of ArrayRates objects in the collection.
     *
     * @return int          the number of ArrayRates objects in the collection.
     *
     */
    public int getCount()
    {
        return rates.size();
    }
```

Comment: I see nothing wrong the above code.  That being said, it appears to be cut off and also your constructor is just creating a plain empty `ArrayList`.  If your intention was to pass data with which to create to an `ArrayFun` object, you haven't succeeded.

Comment: That was my intention. Thank you. It was cut off, i'm trying to keep questions as short and to the point as possible, I tend to be long-winded, and had a few complaints about questions being too long.

Comment: good practice is with collection is to provide new ArrayList<ArrayRates>(0);

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with you code since **this** refers to the current instance of a particular object.

Another approach could be initializing when you declare rates.

```
public class ArrayFun
{
    // instance variables
    private ArrayList<ArrayRates> rates = new ArrayList<ArrayRates>();

    // constants
    /**
     * Tolerance variable when comparing floating point values in sort method.
     */
    public static final double SORT_DELTA = .001;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class ArrayFun.
     */
    public ArrayFun()
    {


    }

    /**
     * Return the number of ArrayRates objects in the collection.
     *
     * @return int          the number of ArrayRates objects in the collection.
     *
     */
    public int getCount()
    {
        return rates.size();
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code, in fact this is commonly used in all projects.